# Identify injectables and test units

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, software-design

Let's say we have a class with at least one visible method and several private methods. The visible one calls the private ones, the private ones call other private ones and so on. There is a *unit test* that 100% covers all paths of the class including in its private methods.

At certain point a developer decides to extract some of the private methods in another class, because the original class is too big. There is no chance for reuse of the extracted code as it is usable only for the original class.

Now there is a second class that needs to be instantiated somewhere in order to be able to use its method(s). The new class now has lets say one visible method.

Questions:

1. Should the new class be a dependency that is a matter of *dependency injection*? Or it is considered a helper that can be instantiated where it makes sense (constructor or method)?
2. Should we write an additional unit test for the new class?
3. Should the parameters in the visible method of the new class be validated again if they are already validated in the original class?

The problem is general and there are no concrete examples.

Answer (score 2):

The code smell you encountered is called [Constructor Over-Injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/) and your resulting refactoring is very similar to the [Facade Services refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) which (according to [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (§6.1.2, page 168)) is defined as:

> *A Facade Service hides a natural cluster of interacting **Dependencies**, along with their behavior behind a single **Abstraction**.*

For your refactoring to be the Facade Services refactoring, however, it prescribes the use of a new abstraction and the abstracted behavior hides one or more dependencies. If the extracted logic has *no dependencies*, and contains no volatile behavior (see below), consider making the method static.

> 1 Should the new class be a dependency that is a matter of dependency injection? Or it is considered a helper that can be instantiated where it makes sense (constructor or method)?

Both options are viable, and it depends on a lot of factors what the best solution is. Things you might want to ask yourself is:

- *Does the extracted logic belong in the same module as the original class belongs?* If not, the [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) prescribes hiding external code behind an abstraction and injecting it into the constructor.
- *Does the extracted logic contain [volatile behavior](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/230)?* In other words, does its logic need to be replaceable in any way or form (such as Mocked during testing, replaced using the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), or decorated or intercepted to apply [Cross-Cutting Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern))? In that case the behavior should be abstracted and injected into the constructor, because it would otherwise hinder testability and maintainability.
- *Are the dependencies of that helper class expected to change regularly?* In that case the dependency should at least be injected into the constructor, because otherwise a change in dependencies of the helper ripples to the consuming class.

In general, I’m inclined to say that your best bet is to define a new abstraction for this helper class and inject it into the constructor. When in doubt, I’d certainly go with this option, because defining new abstractions sometimes leads to new insights into the application's domain.

> 2 Should we write an additional unit test for the new class?

That depends. From a testing perspective, you can still decide to test the class and its helper together. This allows you to keep the logic in the tests the same. Complicated classes often tend to have a complicated set of tests with them. From that perspective it might make sense to test both classes in isolation, and perhaps have a few tests that test the two classes in integration. If your tests already covered most cases, you should be able to reuse most of your test code.

> 3 Should the parameters in the visible method of the new class be validated again if they are already validated in the original class?

If you find the urge to revalidate a set of parameters, consider extracting them into a [Parameter Object](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object). The Parameter Object's constructor can do the validation, and you can pass the Parameter Object from client to consumer, and from consumer to helper.